# Simulate the same effect as background-attachment fix for SVG text fill property

Tags: css, svg, background-attachment

I have an SVG with a `<text fill='url(#img1)'>Hello</text>` however, when scrolling I would like to get a parallax effect with the background by doing the same I would on a div setting its background with `background-attachment:fixed`.

Is there any way to achieve that out-of-the-box with SVG?
I know [Raphaël.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) achieve this by manipulating the `patternTransform` matrix within the `pattern` element, however I would like to achieve this without the need for additional scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sorry. You can't do what you want with pure SVG.  The only sort-of workaround I can think of is a mixed SVG+HTML solution where your text was actually a hole in a solid colour shape (eg a `<rect>`) through which you could see the background of the `<svg>`s parent element. And put the background on the parent element.

Ie. something like:

```
<div style="background:url(foo); background-attachment:fixed">
   <svg>
      <defs>
         <mask id ="mytext">
            <text>My text</text>
         </mask>
      </defs>
      <rect mask="url(#mytext)"/>
   </svg>
</div>
```

This has been simplified for clarity, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: thanks @bigbadaboom, the only thing is that the mask `text` might need a `rect` before it so it can cut-out, setting fill to white on the rect insider the mask and the colour wanted on the rect outside

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I probably simplified it a bit too much. :)  I'm glad you understood what I meant anyway.